# Magento export customers who are not unsubscribed

Tags: magento

Is there a way in Magento admin panel to export customers who are not unsubscribed i.e.

`Required_Customers = All_Customers - Unsubscribed_Customers`

In this way, I will get:

`new_customers(who have not subscribed) + subscribed_customers - unsubscribed_customers(who subscribed once but then unsubscribed)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change code like this

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('ns'=>'newsletter_subscriber'), 'ns.customer_id=e.entity_id', array('substatus'=>'ns.subscriber_status') );

foreach($collection->getData() as $customer){
    if($customer['substatus']!=1){
        print_r($customer);
    }
}
```

you can modify if condition as per your requirement.